# How to Find the first image in post content and add it to Featured Image

Tags: wordpress, bulkupdate

I have about 1000 posts on my wordpress website, but these posts do not have featured images. But instead, in all these posts there is one photo (the first photo in the article) that can be used as an index photo.
How to find the first photo of the article in bulk and replace the featured photo. (The first photo in the article can be deleted)

I would appreciate if u helped me with this.

I tried to manually replace these photos, but there are too many posts. I read some articles in different forums about the possibility of using Python to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Quite old post, but I'm facing the same problem, so I figured I'd provide what I found.

### First solution (paid)

There is an existing WordPress plugin called [Quick Featured Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-featured-images/) whose pro version offers what you need (at least I figured reading their presentation, I did not test it myself).

The base plan was a bit under 80$ with taxes last time I checked.

### Second solution (free)

If you want something less easy but free, I found [an article](https://www.gavick.com/blog/wordpress-automatically-set-post-featured-image) and [a support ticket on a WordPress theme](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/set-the-first-image-in-the-post-as-featured-image/) that mentioned the following bit of code :

```php
function auto_featured_image() {
    global $post;
 
    if (!has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
        $attached_image = get_children( "post_parent=$post->ID&amp;post_type=attachment&amp;post_mime_type=image&amp;numberposts=1" );
         
      if ($attached_image) {
              foreach ($attached_image as $attachment_id => $attachment) {
                   set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $attachment_id);
              }
         }
    }
}
// Use it temporary to generate all featured images
add_action('the_post', 'auto_featured_image');
// Used for new posts
add_action('save_post', 'auto_featured_image');
add_action('draft_to_publish', 'auto_featured_image');
add_action('new_to_publish', 'auto_featured_image');
add_action('pending_to_publish', 'auto_featured_image');
add_action('future_to_publish', 'auto_featured_image');
```

I did not find any free plugin that already does this, so I plan on creating a really simple one that implements this code and works with the last version of WordPress, nothing complicated.

If I find the time to do it I'll update my answer with a link to the plugin I created.

EDIT : I found [this other StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55148330/wordpress-setting-first-image-as-featured-image-for-older-posts) that also use the code I mentioned, but it does not seem to work for everything. Will look into the answer that was provided too.

Comment: thank you for the answer but, If I use this code for all posts, it won't get a 500 error from the server? Where in the code exactly finds the photo inside the text?

Comment: @MortezaAhmadi What this code does is each time a post is displayed, saved, published, it will execute the function above. This function uses a query to find the first attachment in the post (terminology to find an image) and sets it to the post thumbnail. If the post already has a thumbnail, the post is left unchanged. This works for recent posts, but it does not seem to work for older articles as mentioned in my edit. If you need more compatibility, I would recommend using existing plugins.

Comment: I wrote a plugin for this, but there is a problem that when this edit is going to be done in a large number (such as 200 posts), after a few seconds I get error 500. I even set a delay of 2 to 5 seconds for the execution of each series of tasks, but I still have this problem.. i used sleep function .. How to avoid 500 error in large tasks.

Comment: @MortezaAhmadi This may be another issue due to timeout or some other server error. Maybe you could create another question about it and link it here? For a quick tip, see this other post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914257/difference-between-set-time-limit-and-ini-setmax-execution-time